# Symfony3 - Background task launched by controller and send email when finished

Tags: php, asynchronous, background-process, symfony

I have some functions taking a lot of time and I want them to be executed in the background and to send an email when it's finished. 
These functions generate a PDF as Response and if possible, I want this PDF to be attached to email.

This is the standalone function that takes a lot of time :

```
$passages = $em->getRepository(PasserColle::class)->calculClassementAction($id, $group);
```

This function is included in my Controller in a function imprimerAction($id, $request) that returns :

```
return new Response($html2pdf->Output('Classement.pdf'), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
```

I tried to use the Process Component but I can't make it work since I don't understand what to type in the parenthesis :

```
$process = new Process('ls -lsa');
```

And how to get the output I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **RabbitMQ** to do this and this [bundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmqbundle) for Symfony.

The concept is simple. You'll  have *Producers* who will send messages (with the format you want) and *Consumers* who will consume these messages. Messages are published in an exchange and will be routed into queue where Consumers are waiting for new messages.

In your example, you can produce a message which tell to *Consumers* to do a pdf generation and to send email. Publish a message in format JSON for example with, in your case, `$id` and `$group` and Consumers will do what they have to do.

Follow this [link](https://inviqa.com/blog/let-rabbitmq-do-work-your-symfony2-application) that explain how you can do this.

Otherwise, if you want to use Process Component, you can simple create a *Command Console* and then do this : `$process = new Process('php bin/console yourcommand')` and `$process->run()`

I just hope it helps.

Best Regards.

Comment: I'll look into RabbitMQ solution. Thank you !